# How to install X on Nixos

Tags: nixos

I'm using the minimal nixos VM image.

According to: https://nixos.org/nixos/manual/index.html#sec-x11

I just need to add these lines (to `/etc/nixos/configuration.nix` presumably)

```
services.xserver.enable = true;
services.xserver.desktopManager.xfce.enable = true;
```

Once I do a `sudo nixos-rebuild switch` and install xinit via `nix-env -i xinit`, and execute `startx` I get an error of:

```
hostname: Unknown host
xauth: file /home/demo/.serverauth.2821 does not exist
```

Comment: Seems like I'm running an old nixos version (16.09), and it's not maintained. https://github.com/NixOS/nixpkgs/issues/27425#issuecomment-315614688

Answer (score 8):

You don't use `xinit` to start X in nixOS. To do that, enter `systemctl start display-manager.service`. But it should start automatically after you reboot your system, so I think something is misconfigured (maybe you have `services.xserver.autorun` set to `false`?).